How to use unitary matrix for single qubit rotations?
I know, that all single qubit unitaries can be written as:
$$
U = \exp\left(-{\rm i}\,\frac{\Theta\,\sigma \cdot n}{2}\right),
$$
where $\Theta$ is an angle, $n$ is a length $3$ direction vector, and $\sigma = \left(\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z\right)$ is the vector of Pauli matrices:
$$\sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix}
              0 & 1\\
              1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\sigma_y = \begin{pmatrix}
              0 & -i\\
              i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix}
              1 & 0\\
              0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How to use this? For example, I'd like to rotate the qubit state vector around $X-$axis, all I know is that I should use $\sigma_{x}$ operator. But in the abovementioned formula I can't imagine, how to use it.
For example, if I try to multiply $S-$vector by $n-$vector in Python:
sigma = np.array([[[0,1],
          [1,0]],
          [[0, -1j],
          [1j, 0]],
          [[1, 0],
          [0, -1]]])

n = np.array([[1],[0],[0]]

sigma*n

I'll get the ValueError, because sigma has the shape of $\left(3,2,2\right)$ and for $n$ the shape is $\left(3,1\right)$.
I would be very appreciated for those, who can show me by some example, how can I use this single qubit unitary for rotating the qubit around any axis.

If $|\psi\rangle$ is the qubit state vector and $U=e^{-i\Theta\sigma_x/2}$, then $U|\psi\rangle$ is the rotated state vector.

@Semiclassical, for sure, but my question is rather about 'technical' issues, how to multiply such vectors (how to use it in calculations)? Let me add some edits to my question to be more clear)

$\sigma\cdot \hat{n}$ is just shorthand for $\sigma_x n_x+\sigma_y n_y +\sigma_z n_z$, i.e., it's a particular linear combination of the Pauli matrices. As such, $\sigma\cdot \hat{n}$ is always a 2-by-2 traceless hermitian matrix.

@Semiclassical, I know that it may be too boring to you, but could you please show me some example for rotating about any of axes? As I understand, $\sigma_x$  is 2-by-2 matrix and $n_x$ is just the number (coordinate), so if I sum all the matrices I'll get 2-by-2 matrix and I have no idea, how to control whether I applied just $\sigma_x$ or just $\sigma_y$

@Curious  The operator $U$ you defined on the first line corresponds to a rotation around the axis $n$ already.
